# Initd permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel

I'm new to Linux and AWS I'm trying to set up an initd script as this code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dominijk/347ff379605d9e56899c4ef1bc749051) but getting the following error message, which I think related to permissions but I don't understand what thing needs permissions where.

```sh
env: /etc/init.d/geoserver: Permission denied
```

I've tried the following to resolve it;

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-xxx init.d]$ sudo chmod +x geoserver start
[ec2-user@ip-xxx init.d]$ service geoserver start
Starting geoserver...
/etc/init.d/geoserver: line 33: /run/geoserver.pid: Permission denied
```

EDIT: The machine is AWS Linux 2 RHEL 7.6 Maipo

Comment: `sudo service geoserver start` ?

Comment: Thank you, that got me to the next step which was to give the user running geoserver the correct permissions to write log files. Now up and running.